# Texpad and BibTeX, empty .bbl/.blg file generated

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, texpad

My name is J.T. in this board. I am a senior student in a Japanese university, and writing a thesis for my graduation using Texpad. When I change the way to manage bibliography; I wrote bibliography directly on a .tex file before, but I wanted to manage .bib file.

I made a .bib file. My graduate thesis is in Japanese so I set pLaTeX->dvipdfmx + BibTeX for compiling. In the end of .tex file, I wrote

```
\bibliographystyle{jplain}
\bibliography{bibliography}
```

,where jplain is a Japanese plain style including Japanese articles or books in .bib file. I saved the .bib file as bibliography.bib.

I pressed typeset button, but the place where I cited was [?] and there is no bibliography space in the pdf file. I checked the same directory where the .tex file placed. .bbl file has been created in the directory but there is no characters just made a file.

> P.S. I read theses written in English but I don't write English so you
>   may confuse this. But I was wondering if you could help the problem.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Did you rerun pLaTeX after running bibtex?

Comment: The editor Texpad is automatically typeset these steps. You mean platex->bibtex->platex ?

Comment: I created the bibliography file on BibDesk for mac.

Comment: Yes I meant  the sequence platex->bibtex->platex (and sometimes a 3rd run of platex), just  the same as latex ->bibtex …

Comment: The process I need to do in Texpad? I just checked the typeset setting 'bibtex' box.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know TeXpad. I can only give general advice.

Comment: Thanks Bernard, I will keep seeking the solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

What I found has helped me (when I get an empty or non-existant .bbl, .blg, or other auxiliary files while using a graphical TeX editor) is to run each command separately.

That is, instead of using a predefined command string (e.g.,`pdflatex -> bibtex -> pdflatex -> pdflatex`) or the default compile or compile & view button, literally run each command in your sequence by itself and inspect the resulting issues/log file.  You may not see errors directly related to the generation of your .blg or .bbl files unless you run `bibtex`, `biber`, etc. by itself.

See [this link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63852/question-mark-instead-of-citation-number) for helpful tips on troubleshooting bibliography issues.